# lightning:fileUpload displayed as disabled in community

Tags: lightning, community, fileupload

I'm trying to implement file upload functionality following the instructions in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm). But the uploader is being displayed as a disabled input.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="0031800000SEgfD" />
<lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"        
                                  multiple="true"
                                  accept=".pdf, .png"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" 
                                  disabled="false"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        alert('before upload');
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
    }
)}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, I explicitly tried to set the disabled to false hoping that changes something even though it is the default state.

Has anyone ran into this before? The documentation says this behavior is expected when used in Lightning Out or standalone apps only. There is a mention of file size limits in communities, which makes me think it should be working in communities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forcibly add the component to an Object record page, otherwise the ID will not bind to your component attribute, I had the same behavior a while back when implementing it. Note, the component whne using it with a community record page:
[image]

and Home page:

[image]

eventhough i have a default recordId as you do.

Comment: This functionality is not a part of the object record page. It is embedded in a Build Your Own Community page. i'm grabbing the contact record id based on the logged in user.

Comment: in my experience, you cant go about using the component anywhere in your community, hence my comment in regards to the record detail page

Comment: I have developed a solution using lightning:input, but it can accept only up to 1 MB size files. The other option is to develop a VF page as it allows up to 10 MB and wrap it in a lightning component. I was hoping to overcome these limitations by using lightning:fileUpload. Are you aware of any other solutions?

Comment: not that i am aware of

Comment: It's a step backwards from apex for file uploads, frustrating but I imagine it will be fixed in a few years