# Drag and Drop - multi file upload in Custom Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, fileupload

I want to create a drag and drop multi-file upload in a lightning component form. The form is displayed in a community.

I have used

```
<lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt" 
                                  multiple="true" 
                                  accept=".pdf, .png, .jpeg, .jpg, .txt, .xls, .xlsx, .doc, .docx"
                                  disabled="false"
                                  recordId="{!v.dummyContactRecordId}"
                                  onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

to upload a file. However, the issue here is that, for guest user the fileUpload comes as disabled. Is there any way to make it enabled? Or is there any other way to create a multi-drag and drop?

Comment: Look at [lightning:fileUpload displayed as disabled in community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213294/lightningfileupload-displayed-as-disabled-in-community)

Answer (score 0):

> However, the issue here is that, for guest user the fileUpload comes as disabled.

This is because, the component is **not** supported for Guest Users in Communities.

Here's the excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) (refer to *File Upload Limits*
section in the documentation):

> Guest users can't add files to Communities.

---

You alternative here could be possibly using [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) (*type="file"*).

Answer (score 0):

Since, it's already an idea posted to give Guest User access to upload files in Salesforce, so you can do anything for now:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8ppQAC